# gnu make recipe / target written with % not working

Tags: makefile, gnu, gnu-make

Using GNU Make 3.81

The error I'm getting is:

> make: No rule to make target "unittest/build/inMessages.o", needed by "unittest/build/xlineunittestrunner".  Stop.

I have the target written in the makefile as such:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.c
  $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) -c $< -o $@
```

If I replace `%` (in `$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.c`) with `inMessages`, it works. I'm not sure why `%` isn't matching `inMessages`.

EDIT:

I don't think the issue is there is some other rule matching .o files. Here are the complete list of rules from the makefile:

```
all: printinfo checkdirs $(BUILDDIR)/xlineunittestrunner

printinfo:
  @echo "SRCS = $(SRCS)" 
  @echo "OBJ  = $(OBJ)"
  @echo "SOURCEDIRS = $(SOURCEDIRS)" 
  @echo "OBJECTS    = $(OBJECTS)"
  @echo "OBJECTSTOBUILD = $(OBJECTSTOBUILD)"
  @echo "BUILDDIR = $(BUILDDIR)"  

$(BUILDDIR)/xlineunittestrunner: $(OBJECTSTOBUILD)
  $(CC) -o $@ -c $^

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.c
  $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) -c $< -o $@

checkdirs: $(BUILDDIR)

$(BUILDDIR):
  @mkdir -p $@
```

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else in the makefile that might interfere with the pattern rule? Maybe something that calls for some other dependency that isn't there in the case of `inMessages`, like maybe `$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.h`?

Comment: Also, how is this rule being invoked?  Do you just type `make` and have Make pick up the first rule in the Makefile, or are you typing `make something`?

Comment: It's being invoked as `make all`. Make all invokes <checkdirs> <target>, checkdirs just creates /build if it's not there. Target checks first for object files, then checks .c files and builds the object files, finally linking the executable. Somehow my target for object/c files is messed up and not pattern matching...

Answer (score 0):

When you replace `%` with `inMessages` it turns the implicit pattern rule into an explicit rule. Explicit rules have priority over implicit pattern rules. It must be that there is another pattern rule that produces `%.o`.

I would try running make with `-d -p` and see which rule matches. Also `-r` switch may be useful to disable the built-in implicit pattern rules if you don't use them.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. If there were another pattern rule whose prereqs existed (or could be made), then Make might run that rule instead of this one; if the prereqs of that other rule did not exist (and could not be made), then Make would run this rule. Either way, we wouldn't get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. The problem was a (extra character) typo in adding sourcedirs to VPATH. Pattern matching was working, it just couldn't find any source code files.

Answer (score 0):

do below change it will work

> %.o: %.c:
>
> ```
>       $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) -c $< -o $(BUILDDIR)/$@
> ```

Logic is $(BUILDDIR)/%.o and $(BUILDDIR)/$@ are same.

if you cann't target change the recipe :)